# href inside loop javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to loop trough all my delicious.com bookmarks and wrap a link arround them...

here's my testsite:
http://dev.thomasveit.com/json.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){               
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/tommyholiday",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(data){
                var bookmarks = $.map(data, function(bookmark){
                    return {
                        title: bookmark.d,
                        link: bookmark.u
                    }
                });                 

                var html = "<ul>",
                    m;

                for (i=0; i<bookmarks.length; i++){
                    m = bookmarks[i];

                    html += "<li><a href="+m.link+">"+m.title+"</a></li>";
                }
                html += "</ul>";

                $("#delicious").html(html);

            }                       
        });
});
```

funnily enough only the third link is getting wrapped by a link... the others not.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a href` attribute need quotes.

```
html += "<li><a href="+m.link+">"+m.title+"</a></li>";
```

should be

```
html += "<li><a href='"+m.link+"'>"+m.title+"</a></li>";
```

Comment: There's a problem in your link, then. It shouldn't contain a space. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @dystroy Yes, but when check the must not please. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-unquoted

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add quotes " to the `href` attribute.

For example:

```
<li><a href=http://www.designtnt.com/500-free-photoshop-patterns-your-web-designs/>500+ Must-Have Free Photoshop Patterns for Your Web Designs</a></li>
```

If you look at that link, it url ends with `/` and closes the `<a>` tag. The text then comes after the `a` tag and the the last `</a>` is ignored.

In my opinion the best way to create html tags is to use the DOM for both performance and bugs.

```
var ul = document.createElement("ul");

// inside the for
var li = document.createElement("li");
var a_tag = document.createElement("a");
a_tag.setAttribute("href", m.link);
a_tag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(m.title));
li.appendChild(a_tag);

// add the li
ul.appendChild(li);

// end for
$("#delicious").html(ul);
```